# How to change the width of the labelled area in legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I understood how to change the width of the plot lines in my legend, how can I get the same result for the area?
Here I report my code that I wrote using `tikzpicture`:
(I'm sorry for the large amount of data)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Set font style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
% for pgf images
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{import}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}%[tbtags]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left,trim axis right]
            
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.99216,0.91765,0.79608}%
            
    \pgfplotsset{
        width=0.3\textwidth,
        height=0.3\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        tick align = inside,
        scaled x ticks = false,
        title style={font=\bfseries},
        tick label style = {font=\scriptsize},
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, font=\tiny},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
        at={(0\textwidth,0\textwidth)},
        stack plots=y,
        xmin=450,
        xmax=600,
        xlabel={Wavelength (nm)},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        ylabel={Normalized Intensity [a.u.]},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=2,
        set layers=axis on top,
        clip=true,
        clip mode=individual,
        legend image code/.code={
            \draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2]
            plot coordinates {
                (0cm,0cm)
                (0cm,0cm)        %% default is (0.3cm,0cm)
                (0.25cm,0cm)         %% default is (0.6cm,0cm)
            };%
        }
    }
            
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis y line*=left,
        name=first
    ]
                        
        \addplot[area style, color=mycolor1, fill=mycolor1, on layer=main]
        table[row sep=crcr]{%
            ...data...
        }
        \closedcycle;
        \label{Laser}
    \end{axis}
        
\begin{axis}[%
    axis y line*=right,
    tick label style = {color=white},
    label style={color=white},
    axis x line=none
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Laser}\addlegendentry{Laser Emission}
        \addplot [color=blue, line width=0.8pt, on layer=axis grid]
        table[row sep=crcr]{%
            ...data...
        };
    \addlegendentry{546Film Absorption}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I wish that the light orange area in legend had the same width as the blue plot line in the legend.

Thanks to all
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine `area legend/.style`:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    area legend/.style={
        legend image code/.code={
            \draw[#1](0cm,-0.1cm)rectangle
                (0.25cm,0.1cm) %% default is (0.6cm,0.1cm)
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Set font style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}% really? current version is 1.16

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.99216,0.91765,0.79608}%
    \pgfplotsset{
        width=0.3\textwidth,
        height=0.3\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        tick align = inside,
        scaled x ticks = false,
        title style={font=\bfseries},
        tick label style = {font=\scriptsize},
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, font=\tiny},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
        at={(0\textwidth,0\textwidth)},
        stack plots=y,
        xmin=450,
        xmax=600,
        xlabel={Wavelength (nm)},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        ylabel={Normalized Intensity [a.u.]},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=2,
        set layers=axis on top,
        clip=true,
        clip mode=individual,
        legend image code/.code={
            \draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2]
                plot coordinates {
                    (0cm,0cm)
                    (0cm,0cm)        %% default is (0.3cm,0cm)
                    (0.25cm,0cm)         %% default is (0.6cm,0cm)
                };%
        },
        % redefine the area legend:
        area legend/.style={
            legend image code/.code={
                \draw[#1](0cm,-0.1cm)rectangle
                    (0.25cm,0.1cm) %% default is (0.6cm,0.1cm)
                ;
            }
        }
    }
            
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis y line*=left,
        name=first
    ]
        \addplot[area style, color=mycolor1, fill=mycolor1, on layer=main]
        table[row sep=\\]{%
            520 0.5\\
            570 1\\
        }
        \closedcycle;
        \label{Laser}
    \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis y line*=right,
    tick label style = {color=white},
    label style={color=white},
    axis x line=none
]

    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Laser}
    \addlegendentry{Laser Emission}
    \addplot [color=blue, line width=0.8pt, on layer=axis grid]
        table[row sep=\\]{%
            500 0.5\\
            550 1\\
        };
    \addlegendentry{546Film Absorption}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks!!!